# How to mockery a class in a trait called by an event?

Tags: laravel, mockery

I'm not able to mock a class inside a trait class that is called by an "updated" event.

In my phpunit:

```
public function setUp()
{
    ...

    $this->mock = \Mockery::mock(NewsletterGateway::class);

    app()->instance(NewsletterGateway::class, $this->mock);

    ...
}

public function test_method()
{
    ...
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('updateData')
               ->once();

    $privacy->update(['firstname' => 'Philipp']);
    ...
}
```

And in my trait

```
namespace App\Newsletter;

use App\Newsletter\NewsletterGateway as Newsletter;


trait UpdatesNewsletter
{ 
    protected static function bootUpdatesNewsletter()
    {
       static::updated(function ($model){
          $model->updatesNewsletter();
       });
    }

    //called by the updated event
    protected function updatesNewsletter() 
    {
        $newsletter = new Newsletter; 

        dd($newsletter); //still the normal class     
    }

}
```

I'm actually not sure how to mock this. One way was to mock the parent class, but that is not really what I want (don't want to mock other method names).

How would you mock in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Good for me but I needed to change my code and needed to use Jobs. So with that it was pretty easy to test it:

```
/** @test */
public function it_updates_newsletter_when_user_privacy_is_updated() 
{    
    Queue::fake();

    $privacy = create('App\UserPrivacy', ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);

    $privacy->update(['firstname' => 'Philipp']);

    Queue::assertPushed(ProcessUpdatesNewsletter::class);

}
```